# Getting 'illegal start of type' when compiling

Tags: java, compiler-errors

```
 public class WriteByteArrayToFile {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String strFilePath = "C://Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_23/bin//s.excel";
        try
        {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(strFilePath);
            int numberBytes = fileinputstream.available();
            byte bytearray[] = new byte[numberBytes];
            fileinputstream.read(bytearray);
            for(int i= 0;i < numberBytes;i++)
            {
                System.out.println(bytearray[i]);
            }
            fileinputstream.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
            MyReader mr = new MyReader();
            mr.ReadFile("side1-60.java");
        }

        String strContent = "side1-60.java ";
        fos.write(strContent.getBytes());
        fos.close();
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("FileNotFoundException : " + ex);
    }
    catch(IOException ioe) {    
        System.out.println("IOException : " + ioe);
    }
}
```

This is my code. I am getting error as `illegal start of type` when I'm compiling, particularly at `catch(FileNotFoundException e)`. Can anyone p;ease help me to overcome this?

Comment: If you indented your code sanely, you'd see your last two catch blocks are attached to your `main` method, not your try block.

Comment: @system32 that would not cause this error...

Answer (score 1):

code having only one `try` block.

```
 catch(Exception e)
                    {
                    System.out.println(e);
        MyReader mr = new MyReader();
        mr.ReadFile("side1-60.java");           
        }
```

**// this code is causing problem , there is no continues code for catch blocks**

```
    String strContent = "side1-60.java ";

     fos.write(strContent.getBytes());

     fos.close();

catch(FileNotFoundException f){
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I edited your code and fixed indentation - something you should do every time when you write your code.  As you can now see, you are closing your try-catch block and then executing more code.

Then you're closing the method - and after that you have your `catch(FileNotFoundException e)`.  This `catch` block appears after the method is completed - so either a member variable or another method is expected - hence you get this error.

As I don't know your logic, I can't tell you what it needs to be - but the way it is now, it's definitely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your Code can't work, you forget to declare "fileinputstream" and your try-catch is not valid. You try to write code between two catch-Blocks.